# Rails Issue - Displaying Errors During Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

In my Rails 4 app I have two models - `users` and `accommodations`. `Users` has many `accommodations` and it has been set up in the relevant models (i.e. `belongs_to`, `has_many`, etc). I'm trying to validate data added to my accommodations model and display errors if there are any.

When I try to access `accommodations/new` action, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Accommodations#new
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

I have this working for when my users try and register and here is the code:

`users/new.html.erb:`

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <p class="error"><%= msg %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but when I try to do the same with accommodation I get the error mentioned:

`accommodations/new.html.erb:`

```
<% if @accommodation.errors.any? %>
    <% @accommodation.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <p class="error"><%= msg %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

After reading around I realise that the first one works because of this in the `UsersController:`

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

but after trying the following in my AccommodationsController #new action it still won't work

```
@accommodation = Accommodation.new
```

My `Accommodation` model is as follows:

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

Comment: post your index.html.erb

Comment: Share your Accommodations controller index action, model and full error message.

Comment: I have nothing in my Accommodations index action as I'm not sure what to put there! I have edited the post with my Accommodation model and an extra line of the error message

Comment: @tommyd456 are you see my answer ?

Comment: That error means the receiver of the `#errors` method is `nil`. In your case, that means the `@accommodations` instance variable. I can't say whether the content and filenames of your controllers and views are alright because you only posted snippets of those files. Also, remember you can only view errors after you make a specific call for validation, such as `#valid?` or `#save`.

Comment: I'm following the Rails guide on their website and this is how they do it! The form on the new.html.erb points to the create like it does for my user registration page - if there are validation issues then new is rendered and the errors appear

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. That's still unrelated to your instance variable being nil. Did you put the `@accomodation = Accommodation.new` statement in the `#new` action in `AccommodationController`?

Comment: Yes I mentioned this in the question - it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: sorry @depa - one little problem - got everything going except I had @accommodation=current_user.accommodations.build(accommodation_params) in my create action - build is not recognised anymore?

Comment: In has_one associations that method gets replaced by `build_accommodation`

Answer (score 2):

In the `new` method of your controller, you should use `current_user.accommodations.build` instead of `accommodation.new`, because you want an new accomodations of a user (accomodation belong_to user). when we have this type of relation remember that `.new` become `.build` instead

you have relation between users and accomodations like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :accommodations

end
```

and :

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user

end
```

you should have a new method like this :

```
class AccommodationsController < ApplicationControlle
   def new
      @accommodation = current_user.accommodations.build
   end
end
```

note : **here current_user is user who is logged in** .

then in your `create` method, i think if an error occurs you render `new`, else if creation succeed you redirect to `accommodations#index` page ?

in this case you should add index action to your accommodations controller :

```
class AccommodationsController < ApplicationControlle

    def index
       # add here what do you need to show, i think you want to show all accomodations, so just add the following line (you can also add pagination if you want later) :
       @accommodations = Accommodation.all
    end

    .
    .
end
```

finally you should have an `index view page`  :  `views/accommodation/index.html.erb` which loop for each element in `@accommodations` and show what do you need as information ...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response - I have edited the original question slightly to clarify but when I add the ruby to display any errors as a results of the validation rules - this is when the NoMethodError occurs

Comment: Yes i have seen it thanks! Doesn't work I'm afraid - my error happens as soon as I add the ruby code to display validation errors (side note: accommodation is spelt with two m's for any who copy and paste).

Comment: and also - the error isn't when I try to submit the form - it's when I try and load accommodations/new

Comment: change [at]accommodation = Accommodation.new with [at]accommodation = current_user.accommodations.build , have you already a method which return the current user (who is connected)

Comment: yes this is what I did - I added to my new action in the Accommodations controller but doesn't work. But it must be something to do with this line because the users controller one works (@user = User.new) - prob has something to do with the relationship

Comment: how do you know the connected user in your app ? have you already a method like current_user ? show us the new error when you change your new method by my code above

Comment: it's the same error - yes I can access current user as I've used this website: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/

Comment: are you logged in when you try to visit the "new" page ?

Comment: please run your console and then try this : 1 --> user = User.first, 2--> accommodation = user.accommodations.build, and tell me if it works, if not what is the error you get

Comment: sorry don't know how to do this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36679/discussion-between-medbo-and-tommyd456)